# Get dropdown values using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Have requirement like, once we click on button need to get dropdown value of the row. I tried below code and getting selected dropdown value fine, but same dropdown option is applying remaining dropdowns as well. Is there any way to update only selected dropdown instead of all ?

.ts

```
   selected(){
    alert(this.selectedLevel)
  }
```

.html

```
<td>   
          <select [(ngModel)]="selectedLevel" (change)="selected()">
  <option *ngFor="let prod of ProductHeader">{{prod.name}}</option>
</select>
     <button class="select" (click)="saveData()">Selected Option</button>   
</td>
```

[Demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-edw9zj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of elements, and that list does not have a `value` property. Also, it looks like you're using angular, so if you properly bind your properties, there should be no need to call DOM methods.

Comment: you are using angular so please mention it in tags rather than typescript. first you dont assign `value` to the `option`, second, all your options are in `ProductHeader` variable and third is that you can assign `[(ngModel)]` to the select which will have the actual selected value inside. It can store object as well, not just string|number.

Comment: Now I'm getting dropdown option on alert, but same option is updated remaining dropdowns as well. Is there anyway to update only selected dropdown ? please suggest. udpated stackblitz as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[(ngModel)]`. For this, first you map your persons adding to properties "check" and "test".

When you get the data, use "map" to add the properties

```
this.http.get(dataUrl).subscribe(response => {
  this.persons = response.data.map(x=>({...x,check:false,test:'test'}));
  this.dtTrigger.next();
});
```

Then you can change your .html, see how to disable you use `[disabled]="!person.check?true:null"`and the `[(ngModel)]="person.check"` and `[(ngModel)]="person.test"`

```
  <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
    <td>
        <input [(ngModel)]="person.check" type="checkbox" 
               class="checkboxCls" name="id"></td>
    <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
    <td>
    <select [disabled]="!person.check?true:null" [(ngModel)]="person.test" 
            (change)="selected(person.test)">
      <option *ngFor="let prod of ProductHeader" [value]="prod.name" >{{prod.name}}</option>
    </select>
    </td>
```

See that you don't need jQuery nor (click) in options and you can pass the value of the test in change function

Your [forked stackblizt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-phtpfc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)